# Can't use bootstrap Modal inside Angular 2 app

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have an Angular 2 app. I want to use Bootstrap Modal windows. I've just included jquery and bootstrap.js files at the end of the body tag. App loads with no errors, but when I go to the console and do

```
$('body').modal()
```

It says that 'modal function is undefined'.

My body tag

```
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use native Bootstrap JavaScript in Angular for a few reasons, one of which is the lack of typings for TypeScript and the other is that there's no jquery constructor/initializer function either.

You could retrofit the Bootstrap JavaScript into Angular, but several libraries have done this work for you.  We've had success with the modal in the official ng-bootstrap:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal